# Submitting several commands to sqlite3 in a single command at cli

Tags: macos, sqlite, command-line-interface

On Mac OS Yosemite I use the following version of SQLite:

```
# sqlite3 --version
3.8.5 2014-08-15 22:37:57 c8ade949d4a2eb3bba4702a4a0e17b405e9b6ace
```

And I have 2 commands which run fine at **sqlite3** prompt:

```
.read android.sql
.import words.txt dict
```

The first command above creates 3 tables I need in my Android app (I use [SQLiteAssetHelper](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper) to copy **my.db** into the APK-file).

The second command above fills the `dict` table from a text file.

How can I run both commands **in a single command** at the cli?

I have tried following separators: semicolon, slash and `\\n` but this does not work:

```
echo ".read android.sql / .import words.txt dict" | sqlite3 my.db 
Usage: .read FILE
```

**UPDATE:**

This does work in Mac OS Terminal (thanks, Mark) -

```
# echo -e "command1\ncommand2"
command1
command2

# echo -e ".read android.sql\n.import words.txt dict" | sqlite3 my.db 
Usage: .read FILE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo -e "command1\ncommand2" | sqlite3 my.db
```

For example:

```
echo -e ".print hello\n.print goodbye" | sqlite3 
hello
goodbye
```

See help page for `echo` using `bash`'s built-in help:

```
help echo
```

Comment: What *exact* command did you use? Please click `edit` under your question and update it there rather than as a comment.

Comment: My fault - I had missed the `-e` switch. Now it works, thank you

Comment: Excellent! Glad to be of service - you had me worried there for a minute :-)